# Count how many filled lines are in a QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I would like to know how many filled lines are in a QTextEdit.
With one of the following commands i am getting the count of all lines in a QTextEdit.

```
self.ui.textEdit.document().lineCount()
self.ui.textEditdocument().blockCount()
```

For example, if the TextEdit is empty I get 1 back and if a line is filled i also get 1 back

The background is that I am currently developing a contact manager in which each person has different categories in which several values are stored. For example, there is the family category. When I click on the save button, I need to know how many lines with values are in the text field in order to execute update, delete oder add Statements in a database.

Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(326, 266)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 321, 261))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.filedLinesCount)

    def filedLinesCount(self):
        print(self.textEdit.document().lineCount())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the text must be processed:

```
def filedLinesCount(self):
    text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()

    count = 0
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        word = line.strip()
        if word:
            print(word)
            count = +1
    print(count)
```